# Centering a background image?

Tags: css

I am failing to see why I can't get my background image to be positioned center center.

Help?

Comment: no code - just a link - poor!

Comment: The link says it all, in this case. A jsfiddle would have been better, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the height of the `html` element to `100%` in order to get your code to work. Currently, your body has an offset height of 0px.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

To future readers: To center a background, use:
`background-position: center center;`

To keep the background at the same position when a user scrolls, use:
`background-attachment: fixed;`

See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background) for a full reference.

Answer (score 1):

Set `background-position: 50% 50%` and set the `height: 100%` on the `html` element. The height is essential, otherwise, the background gets centered in the wrong space.

Comment: Unless you are using a 100% height already, in which case you shouldn't make any change to `html` because you probably use `min-height`.

Comment: Yes of course, but in this specific case, the height is not specified, and that is the reason why it doesn't work. You can open the site and modify the style in FireBug to see that the height on `html` is the only thing that's missing here.

Comment: I said it for reference to future visitors.